# It is possible to display html content in iOS7 UIAlertView?

Tags: html, uialertview, ios7

Do you know if it's possible to display some html content (through UIWebView or directly) in the UIAlertview component, on iOS7? The "addSubview" method seems to be no more available...
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there wont be `UIAlertView` with custom views anymore, nor `contentView` which Apple changed its mind about, you need to use a custom control like a HUD.

A good alternative will be [SVProgressHUD](https://github.com/samvermette/SVProgressHUD), according to many threads in Apple's forum.

Comment: Too bad they made ​​this change, I'll find another way then. Thank you!

Comment: Yup, they took some bad decisions and this is one of them.

Comment: I finally used [TSAlertView](https://github.com/TomSwift/TSAlertView). It works well!